# Question on rearrangement of double sums

Tags: linear-algebra

I have never learned the algebra of double summations. In the proof for matrix multiplication given in Linear Algebra done right there is a double sum:

$\sum\limits_{r=1}^n C_{r,k}\sum\limits_{j=1}^m A_{j,r}w_j$
=$\sum\limits_{j=1}^m(\sum\limits_{r=1}^n A_{j,r}C_{r,k})w_j$

Can someone explain to me why this step holds?

Also why does this imply the entry in row j column k for matrix multiplication $AC$ for matrices $A$ and $C$ is defined by

$\sum\limits_{r=1}^n A_{j,r} C_{r,k}$?

Comment: Shoudn't the RHS in the first expression contain at least one series where $r$ ranges from $1$ to $n$

Comment: The most useful response to this question might be the non-answer "Set $n = 2$ and $m = 3$, fully expand the left-hand side, then regroup the terms to get the right-hand side."

Answer (score 1):

Think of the expression on the left hand side as a series of series.

$C_{1,k}(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}A_{j,1}w_j)+C_{2,k}(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}A_{j,2}w_j)+....C_{n,k}(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}A_{j,n}w_j)$

Try rewriting the general $z^th$ term of the series above. Mind you the $z^th$ term is a series itself.

$T_z=C_{z,k}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{m}A_{j,z}w_j$

So the series can be rewritten as $\sum\limits_{z=1}^{n}T_z$ (Right?)

Expand the series and you have the answer. For the explanation about the resultant of matrix multiplication, you have to read linear maps again from the same book. I would suggest reading how the author explains the transformation of linear maps and his notation of vectors in a resultant matrix.